# Using XAML style on CodeBehind

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

Guys im trying to using a style from Style.xaml into my code behind
on my style i have a code like this

file Style.xaml

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontGrey" Color="#FFC5C0C0"></SolidColorBrush>
```

and on my Apptest.xaml.cs file i have code like this

```
txt.Foreground =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 252, 147, 25));
```

if i want to change my foreground color base on style.xaml
how can i do that? i was trying using resources but it doesnt work

note: Style.xaml and Apptest.xaml are separated

Answer (score 3):

You can access your defined resources, in Silverlight, by using the following syntax:

```
txt.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["FontGrey"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your style into Window.Resources in Apptest.xaml like this:

```
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
              Source="Style1.xaml">
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in window code behind file Apptest.xaml.cs you can access to resource:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    txt.Foreground = Resources["FontGrey"] as SolidColorBrush;
```

Comment: thx for your attention sir where should i add that code?
on Apptest.xaml or on Style.xaml? because when im tring to put that code on Style.xaml it doesnt work. thanks before :))

Comment: In your window's code behind class in Apptest.xaml.cs, you can put it after call InitializeComponent(), for example

Comment: so it be like after this.initializeComponent(); then <ResourceDictionary>, coz i think its xaml language, sorry if i dont catch your point, because im still a nooob and i want to learn :))

Comment: when i trying to put that code inside page.resource its ask for an associated key (Each dictionary entry must have an associated key). so what does its mean?

Comment: Have you some other resources in Page.Resources except ResourceDictionary?

Comment: Try to put all of them after row </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

Comment: it doesnt work because it got error on initializeComponent

i think i will use code like    txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(252, 252, 147, 25));    since its produce a same output thanks for your time though :))

Answer (score 1):

If assume that resources is avaliable, than this code should work for you:

```
txt.Foreground = (Brush)FindResource("FontGrey");
```

Comment: thanks for ur atenttion sir.... but on my code FindResource function was not found.

Comment: Check your using and here is a msdn [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.application.findresource.aspx) about that function.

Comment: I mean my FindResources function is not provided, when im typing FindRes.. its not provided yet, how i fix this? Thanks for your attention sir

Comment: This method is not available in Silverlight.